# Electron package dlls and config

Tags: c#, angular, configuration, package, electron

I am looking how to package dlls and configuration files using electron-builder or electron-packager. I have searched the documentation for both and do not see and example on where to put the configuration files or dlls when packaging. Here are a few specifics of the application.

1. This is an angular/electron integration
2. 5 different dlls are being used
3. The dlls need a configuration file that currently exists in 
    ./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe.config
4. The dlls are located in the root folder

The structure is in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sazB.jpg)

Thank you ahead of time for your help

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing.  I've looked all over and haven't been able to find any working examples of electron installers that allow you to install an electron app that calls c# dlls using config.  They never put all the dlls or config in the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `extraFiles` configuration (`electron-builder`), let take a look at document https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents#extrafiles

Your `package.json` should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "build": {
      "win": {
          "extraFiles": [
        {
          "from": "[YOUR_DLL_PATH]", //path to dlls, for example ./lib.dll
          "to": "." //root directory
        }
      }
  }
}
```